# Why isnt json data populating in select element?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a drop down menu using json data. Why isnt any of the data populating? I have tried directly typing 'fitmentData.json' into the url arg as well but nothing is working for me.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="year" id="year">

  </select>

</body>

<script>
  let dropdown = $('year');

  dropdown.empty();

  dropdown.append('<option selected = "true" disabled>Choose 
Year</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

  const url = 'fitmentData.json';

  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', 
entry.year).text(entry.year));
    })
  });

</script>

</html>
```

fitmentData.json

```
[
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "YZ100",
    "year": "1981"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Suzuki",
    "model": "RM100",
    "year": "1978"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "WR250F",
    "year": "2011"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Suzuki",
    "model": "PE175",
    "year": "1978"
   }
 ]
```

yes, i have made sure jquery is working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I was using google chrome and got this error
jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/macbookuser/Desktop/json_dropdown_filter/fitmentData.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I switched to firefox and json data populated just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You selector should be `#year` in stead of just `year`.

```js
let dropdown = $('#year');

  dropdown.empty();

  dropdown.append('<option selected = "true" disabled>Choose Year</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

  const url = 'fitmentData.json';

  let data = [
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "YZ100",
    "year": "1981"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Suzuki",
    "model": "RM100",
    "year": "1978"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "WR250F",
    "year": "2011"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Suzuki",
    "model": "PE175",
    "year": "1978"
   }
 ]
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', 
entry.year).text(entry.year));
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="year" id="year">

  </select>
```

Comment: Choose year now shows up, but json data still doesn’t populate.

Comment: What is your expected output?